# UITableViewAutomaticDimension not correctly sizing UIIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I am trying to set the UITableViewCell height based on what is in the cell (Primarily the image). It looks fine on an iPhone 7 Plus, however any smaller devices produce something similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxpVX.png).

My code in `MainViewController`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

My constraints:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? I have the height and width constraints set to 'Greater or Equal to' 200. The height and width of the UIImageView on the Storyboard are 370x370

Comment: why left and right constraints aren't equal?

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski Both the left and right constraints are equal.

Comment: if Both the left and right constraints are equal, then you don't need define width and height. Then everything will be ok

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski If I don't define my height and width for UIImage then this (http://imgur.com/a/3VFzK) happens when running my app

Comment: Your UIImageView has `AspectFit` wcaling or other ?

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski I changed it to Aspect Fill and the image is now scaling correctly, however it overlaps the text at the top now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136649/discussion-between-adrian-bobrowski-and-gabe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this myself by doing these steps below:

1. Switching my Storyboard View to iPhone SE
2. Setting the UIImageView to 'Greater than or Equal' value: 275
3. Setting the aspect ratio to 1:1 for the width and height of UIImageView

Here's an image as an example:

[image]